# AspectJ operation logging

Tags: logging, interface, aspectj

I have a CUDService interface which holds create,update and delete operations in my project. All of my services implement that interface.
CUDServiceImpl is an abstract class that implements CUDService and has public methods (create,update,delete).
For example I have a StudentService interface with two methods.

```
public interface StudentService extends CUDService,Logged{

addMark();
deleteMark();

}

public class StudentServiceImpl extends CUDServiceImpl implements StudentService{

@Override addmark...
@Override deletemark..


}
```

Notice the Logged interface! It`s an empty interface that i created for marking the Services i want aspectJ to mark for logging.

aspectJ pointcut is defined like this:

execution(* com.history.Logged+.*(..))

and this works for addMark(),deleteMark() methods BUT it doesn`t work for create,update,delete methods that are defined in CUDServiceImpl!
It will work if I would override those methods in StudentServiceImpl class like this:

```
@Override create(){
super.create();
}
```

but I would like to make it work without having to override all of the methods from CUDService.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

CUDServiceImpl doesen't implement Logged interface, therefore its methods are not being cross cutted by aspectj. That is why you have to override it in class that does implement it..